# Unable to connect to the Report Server - Can't find service

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Over the weekend the SQL Server 2008 R2 (running on Windows Server 2008 R2) was rebooted.

This morning my reports don't run.

I try to login to SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services Configuration Manager and it gives  me an error: **Unable to connect to the Report Server**

I did some searches and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143773.aspx#bkmk_nativemode), but I don't see any service called **Report Server**. I also don't see any services that - by its name - seem to be the reporting service when running SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: May get better responses at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: or dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided was for the 2012 version. Use the appropriate version of the link for a few ideas:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143773(v=sql.105).aspx

If the Reporting Services Configuration Manager can't be launched, I would check the system event logs for errors pointing in the right direction: This could be a lot of things: permissions, SQL connectivity problems, certificate expiration, &c.

Edit: the service name is still incorrect in the corret version of the docs I provided. The default instance of this service is called

> SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)

If you have multiple instances of SSRS installed there will be multiple services listed, with the instance name in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, but that article also refers to the **Report Server** service, which I can't find! I didn't see any special events in the event logs. My question is how did that **Report Server** service disappear (if it was ever there)? If someone uninstalled it "by mistake" is there any way I can find that out?

Comment: Jamie, not such service either. I would have figured out that was the one I was looking for. If somebody uninstalled it, is it possible to figure that out?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to determine if it was uninstalled. Running the SQL server installation would be my next step. Select the Add/Remove features option to see what it thinks is installed. Maybe a service pack was getting installed over the weekend and that was interrupted?